# Is there a list of all embedding techniques used in all applications of Machine learning?

Tags: nlp, computer-vision, embedding, word-embedding, knowledge-graph

I started to learn embedding techniques used in machine learning and allied fields. There are word embeddings, graph embeddings, and network embeddings. I was overwhelmed by the various embedding techniques as I googled. Is there a good repository or book or resource that starts with the need for embedding and slowly moves onto different advanced embedding techniques in NLP, Computer Vision, Knowledge Graphs etc.

I need an organic development of the subject so that I can think in different directions and to b able to come up with my own techniques in the embedding space.